# How do I set styles for an image IMG inside <p>?

Tags: html, css

My page structure looks like this:

```
<div class="entry-content">
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p><img></p>
<p></p>
</div>
```

I want to stretch the image to the full width of the container. And I get it when I set such styles:

```
.entry-content p {
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-right: -30px;
}
```

But it works for all `<p>`, and I only need for those that contain `<img>`.

I tried it like this, but this option only nails the image to the left edge.

```css
.entry-content p img {
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-right: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff"></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps in CSS4: `.entry-content p:has(img)` - currently no support

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Selectors** and child properties to simply do this

```
.entry-content> p >img {         // > is used for child 
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-right: -30px;
}
```

you can also used id or class for img tag like this

```
<div class="entry-content">
 <p></p>
 <p></p>
 <p><img id="img1"></p>
 <p></p>
</div>
```

and

```
#img1{
//your styling here
}
```

Comment: This is not a "has"

Comment: Your option doesn't work. The picture is nailed to the left edge and that's it. And you need it to stretch across the width of the block.

Comment: i answer your first part of your question why css is not applying.For second part read absolute css property